# Javascript namespace oop

Tags: javascript, oop

My application needs a namespace. This is my structure atm:

```
function App()
{
   var my_obj1 = new MyObject1();
   var my_obj2 = new MyObject2();
}

MyObject1.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
function MyObject1()
{/*obj1 content*/}

MyObject2.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
function MyObject2()
{/*obj2 content*/}

var app = new App();
```

Do i have to redesign the function head?
Is there a way to set a namespace with my current structure?

Comment: Namespaces in JS are nothing else than properties of objects. So sure, you can just assign each if the variables to a property of a new object, e.g. `NS.App = App` or something like that. I'm not sure what you are asking for.

Comment: Why does your application **need** a namespace?

Comment: Not working with a namespace and a closure is pretty sloppy. You got no guarantee that other third party code is messing your stuff. IMHO there is no excuse not to work in a safe area.

Answer (score 0):

It is **always** a good idea to have a namespace and a closure just for your application. It prevents clashes and global contamination. Just wrap whatever you want in an autoexecuted function that returns an object (or stores it in the global object)

```
(function (window) {

    var APP = {};

    var private = 54; // This var will not be exposed, but accessible in the closure.

    APP.heyhey = function () {alert('heyhey')};
    APP.version = '0.1';


    window.APP = APP;
})(this);
```

And then you just use `APP.heyhey();` and so on.